# Android client connecting to server on pc, using Java sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets, network-programming

I want to send a simple string to a server on my desktop PC. Here is what I have on my PC:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Server Started");
    Server server = new Server();
    server.start();
}

public void start(){
    try {
    ServerSocket SRVSOCK = new ServerSocket(333);
    Socket SOCK = SRVSOCK.accept();
    InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(SOCK.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(ir);

    String MESSAGE = bf.readLine();
        System.out.println(MESSAGE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }
}
```

For my android tablet I have this in the `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   Thread tthread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
       @Override
            public void run() {
                Connect();
            }});
    }

public void Connect(){      
    try {
        Socket SOCK = new Socket("10.0.0.3", 333);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(SOCK.getOutputStream());
        pw.println("FROM ANDROID!");
     } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                   
}
```

I have seen you can create a new thread which you need (otherwise the app UI freezes), but it still does not send the text to my server, I have added the incoming and outgoing port in my windows firewall, and even tried to turn off the firewall, but still no luck..

The android code is running on a real physical tablet (Nexus 7 2013) and not an emulator.

What is wrong here?

This whats in my log cat when the app is opened

```
03-24 13:43:59.695: I/ActivityManager(768): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.hashimo.mcpeworldconverter/.MainActivity bnds=[200,1314]  [400,1590] (has extras)} from uid 10022 on display 0
03-24 13:43:59.780: I/ActivityManager(768): Start proc com.hashimo.mcpeworldconverter for activity com.hashimo.mcpeworldconverter/.MainActivity: pid=6724 uid=10140 gids={50140,    9997, 1028, 1015, 3003} abi=armeabi-v7a
03-24 13:44:00.338: I/ActivityManager(768): Displayed com.hashimo.mcpeworldconverter/.MainActivity: +592ms
```

Comment: You have `Server server = new Server();` what is `Server` ?

Comment: @JonasCz I forgot to get rid of that (this code was from a while ago when i dident know much) the "Server server = new Server();
    server.start();" was just calling the "Start()" method in the SAME class, here "public void start(){...}"

Comment: Are you sure it is actually calling that method ? Put some println's in it and check.

Comment: That 10.0.0.3 IP address in your client code doesn't look look right, can you ping your server from the tablet ? Are there any Exceptions / Stack Traces in LogCat ?

Comment: @JonasCz Yes, its my computers ip... I have found something out. When i go onto my tablets web browser and enter `10.0.0.3:333` and press enter, the server on my pc says `GET / HTTP/1.1`. So it is accessible and working. Plus the app is not crashing what so ever or doing nothing i think... I have the `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` and `INTERNET` permission on my manifest also

Comment: @JonasCz No i dont, But when i run the code with out making a new thread it crashes with some kind of exception

Comment: There should be more in the LogCat, also did you try the Eclipse / Android Studio debugger ?

Comment: Thats all there is, It just opens the app and thats it...(both tablet and pc are on same wireless network too)

Comment: If you have the time and an android device i'd be happy if you could test the code (id give you the classes and stuff, its not private or anything) then you could solve the problem (you seem very smart, other than me #noob)

Comment: Add a pw.flush(); pw.close(); SOCK.close(); Could you already see in server that a client connected? Post much more of the client log.

Comment: @greenapps So i tested this code between both my computers and it kept  crashing but now since i added those things it works now, But still not working from android to pc

Comment: If you cannot better explain what happens and what not happens, and if you do not post a relevant part of the android log then how do you think you get help?

Comment: @greenapps All i know is that there is no crashes what so ever, or any problems. I TESTED this between TWO COMPUTERS (DESKTOP AND LAPTOP) and it works. But when i put the CLIENTS code onto android it does not seem to do the same, instead it just opens the app and thats it. There is nothing in the LOGCAT except it saying it has started my app

Comment: All i want it to do is send a STRING from my android to my COMPUTER(running the server), It does not work at all. BUT WHEN i run the CLIENT off of a COMPUTER it connects to MINE(running the server) and sends the text i want

Comment: simple way: Computer connects to Computer = Works; Android connects to Computer = Fails;

Comment: If your android tablet & Computer are connected to the same wireless network, the computer will not normally get an IP like 10.0.0.3, see if the IP is really that, I will try your code, no need to upload anything, thquestion contains all I need.

Comment: That is my computers `wireless ip4 address`. I even went on my routers main page to see what ip my computer was and it was `10.0.0.3`, And yes all devices and computers on our network (even ethernet ones) have an ip like `10.0.0.XX`

Comment: If the android client can not connect you will have exceptions/error in the logcat. Don't say that there are not. You should put a Log.d statement after every code line and in the catch blocks. Adapt the code here too so we can see what you did and post the resulting logcat.

Comment: Okay, i will, also i am going to recode the app and make it more readable and not so crappy looking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring a Thread but you forgot to .start() it. So your code is not executed.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't see that until now, but OP says that his code works on normal Java but not on android.. Strange.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just started figuring out what `threads` where and their purpose. You are a life saver